# What might cause mouse and keyboard freezes after updating to OSX 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, keyboard, upgrade, mouse, performance

After the 10.8.2 update, keyboard and mouse input is hanging intermittently on my 2011 MacBook Air. It occurs in several applications (have tested with Safari and App Store). The keyboard input and mouse just stops working for a few seconds, then some of the typed text is input at the cursor.

Does anyone know a solution to this or tip to help me find one?

---

**More details**

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoHlzq-QIsU) of the problem by someone with a similar issue.

Console log shows a lot of these

```
2012-09-22 15:22:16,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0x0 returned with result 0xe000404f - retrying
```

Comment: I had the same problem this morning whit the mouse only on OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: @R.M. Did it go away?

Comment: Yes. I restarted the MacBook several times and then the problem went away...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several users have found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19727172#19727172) to work (and as far as I can evaluate, it fixed it for me as well):

- Log in/switch to an administrator account
- open Terminal
- `sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist`
- `sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.google.keystone.daemon.plist`

Comment: Can you please summarize the referenced answer here? The goal is to be not dependent on any remote sites.

Comment: For me it was com.telldus.service.plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was (a super old) version of carbon copy cloners plist:

```
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bombich.ccc.plist
```

removing it brought instant joy (yay!)